# Pandas conditional column addition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
>>df 
L1      L0        desc_L0 
4956    10         Hi
1509    nan        I  am 
1510    20         Here 
1511    nan        where r u ?
```

I want to insert a new column `desc_L1` when value for `L0` is null and same time move respective `desc_L0` value to `desc_L1`.

Desired output:

```
L1      L0       desc_L0      desc_L1
4956    10       Hi           nan
1509    nan      nan          I  am 
1510    20      Here          nan
1511    nan      nan          where r u ?
```

How this can be done in pythonic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy your series:

```
df['desc_L1'] = df['desc_L0']
```

Then use a mask to update the two series:

```
mask = df['L1'].isnull()
df.loc[~mask, 'desc_L1'] = np.nan
df.loc[mask, 'desc_L0'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try so:

```
df['desc_L1'] = df['desc_L0']
df['desc_L1'] = np.where(df['L0'].isna(), df['desc_L0'], np.NaN)
df['desc_L0'] = np.where(df['L0'].isna(), np.NaN, df['desc_L0'])
```

Input:

```
     L0       desc_L0
0  10.0            hi
1   NaN          I am
2  20.0          Here
3   NaN  where are u?
```

Output:

```
     L0 desc_L0       desc_L1
0  10.0      hi           NaN
1   NaN     NaN          I am
2  20.0    Here           NaN
3   NaN     NaN  where are u?
```